# Can we use Map(col1,col2) in select statement

Tags: sql, dictionary, hql, hiveql, impala

I have a requirement to create a map column dynamically in select query

I want to use the map in the select statement

```
select map(col1,col2) from tbl1
```

This is my error:

> AnalysisException: Syntax error in line 1:undefined: select
>   map(cnck.gluten_meal_protein... ^ Encountered: MAP Expected: ALL,
>   CASE, CAST, DEFAULT, DISTINCT, EXISTS, FALSE, IF, INTERVAL, LEFT, NOT,
>   NULL, REPLACE, RIGHT, STRAIGHT_JOIN, TRUNCATE, TRUE, IDENTIFIER CAUSED
>   BY: Exception: Syntax error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`str_to_map(text, [delimiter1, delimiter2])`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-StringFunctions) function. Delimiter1 separates text into K-V pairs, and Delimiter2 splits each K-V pair. Default delimiters are `','` for delimiter1 and `':'` for delimiter2:

```
select str_to_map(concat( 'col1', ':', col1, ',', 'col2', ':', col2 )) as mymap
  from table;
```

You can assign different name to the key, it can be not necessarily equal to column name.

Answer (score 1):

try with this:

```
String HQL_QUERY = "select new map(col1, col2) from Table";        
List<Map<String,String>> usersList = session.createQuery(HQL_QUERY).list();
```

Comment: Hi shouldnt the select query work directly in Impala as well.? Becasue when i do the query alone in impala i am getting the error.